# Can I avoid an instance of WearableListenerService being destroyed by the system?

Tags: android, wear-os

I have an instance of WearableListenerService that must do some network activities on an handheld and give back a response to an Android wear device.

If something goes wrong (for example user gives a wrong address for a server) the system will destroy the WearableListenerService instance within 10 seconds.

Can I avoid this behaviour? Is there a way to increase that timeout? Is there a way to avoid the WearableListenerService being destroyed to give me the ability to execute long running operations on the handheld?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the system's job to deal with a `WearableListenerService` lifecycle.
Never do any asynchronous task in it.
You have to start another `Service` you declare (and that you can manage) to do that.